# An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 2, position 50

Tags: xml, vb.net, error-handling

I am trying to load a Visual Studio VB.NET project from a common server location to Visual Studio 2008 and am not able to so. The error that I am facing is

`An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 2, position 50.`
    `Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class MB_PP_Planner
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub`

Line 2 of the designer does end at position 28 and so i do not how to handle it.

how can i overcome this problem. I looked up the problem on forums and they all suggest removing the & sign in one of the XML files but I do not know which XML document needs to be edited.

The file is loaded properly on the local drive but not through a common server location.

I also tried building the resources again but it still is giving me the same error as earlier.

I am dire need for a solution and would appreciate any help that could be provided.

Comment: One of the controls is not loading correctly.  Did you manually edit the designer.vb file?  Did you put any code before the form constructor : InitializeComponent()?  I would start by commenting out all code in the designer.vb file.  Then slowly add back the commented out code to help isolate where the issue is located.

Comment: thanks for the reply... but i did not try to edit the code in the designer manually niether edited the file. I am currently able to access the same file when stored on my PC's hard disk but not via the server where i am trying to save the file.

Comment: You can't save a file on the server unless the your user account has write permission on the server, or you have admin writes on the server.

Comment: @UtsavMudgal, J.Brown says "I have discovered what is causing my problem . . . an ampersand character (&) in the folder name of the project directory ...  e.g. c:\R&D\Projects".
[ArchivedForum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b346264-b744-43c1-86e8-7486fea87268/vs2005-beta-2-form-designer-problem-error-while-parsing-entityname?forum=winformsdesigner&prof=required)
regards